# LXD profile. How could it be defined? [SOLVED]

Tags: networking, lxc, network-bridge

I am not a sysadmin, so I am almost ignorant on this.
I have a laptop connected via wlan interface and I want to use lxd containers and the network inside the containers.
here
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/07/lxd-networking-lxdbr0-explained/
are mentioned a number of way of doing it.
By mistake I did some of those (and not just one), it was because the first does not work for me.
Now I have:

```
# lxc profile show default
name: default
config: {}
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: macvlan
    parent: eth0
    type: nic
```

I supposed that I should say this

```
# lxc profile device set default eth0 parent wlan0
```

then I have

```
name: default
config: {}
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: macvlan
    parent: wlan0
    type: nic
```

into the container I have:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: eth0@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:16:3e:a8:bc:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

No network connection.
Also, do I need to disable bridge on lxd (with dpkg-reconfigure)?
I have old /etc/default/lxc-net file and lxd-bridge that looks very similar, should I remove the lxc-net?

Thank you

EDIT 1

I switched to bridged network, with this configuration:

```
devices:
  eth0:
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
```

the problem was network port 53 in use (log message reports "address in use"). It was bind listening on 0.0.0.0:53 that is the default.
dnsmasq would to run and can not